# Can I calculate probability by using z-scores if I don't know the population's mean and standard deviation?

Tags: probability, population, z-score

My sample size is $N=100$

Can the Central Limit Theorem be used to justify a probability calculation through z-scores if the population's mean and standard deviation are unknown?

Comment: What kind of probability calculation would you be trying to justify? For some calculations it might be justifiable in some circumstances, but for some other calculations it will not be.

Comment: The point of statistical inference is to determine/estimate the value of specific parameters with for hypothesis testing or confidence interval estimation. You cannot always count on the central limit theorem when the sample size is 100 as some distributions converge too slowly and even some distributions do not have finite means (e.g the Cauchy distribution).